# Duplicate data inserted while failover MongoDB

Tags: replication, mongodb, mongodb-3.4

I'm inserting 3000 documents and in between my primary goes down and secondary becomes new primary I find my application has inserted 3002 documents, 2 documents are duplicate.

What could be the issue? Do we need to set correct write concerns?

Presently writeConcern is 2 and Journaling is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Add unique index what prevents duplicates.

If your data/keys allow, you can use `{upsert:true}` procedure to add documents to collection. If document already exists then it is "updated" and if not, then it is inserted.

Change writeConcern to `{w:"majority", j:true}`.

Comment: If the intent is to avoid duplicate documents only one of the current suggestions works: add a unique index. Write concern is about acknowledgement of writes but does not guarantee uniqueness.